# Flask Gunicorn app can't get __name__ to equal '__main__'

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have this from `/home/myname/myapp/app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

print __name__

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello world!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'in if'
    app.run()
```

When I run:

```
$ gunicorn app:app -b 127.0.0.2:8000
```

It says:

```
2013-03-01 11:26:56 [21907] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.17.2
2013-03-01 11:26:56 [21907] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.2:8000 (21907)
2013-03-01 11:26:56 [21907] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2013-03-01 11:26:56 [21912] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21912
app
```

So the `__name__` of the app is `app`. Not `__main__` like I need it to be to run the if statement. 

I tried putting an empty `__init__.py` in the directory. Here is my `nginx sites-enabled default`:

```
server {
        #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /home/myname/myapp;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.2:8000;
        }
}
```

## Edit

... While this app **does** print `'Hello world'` when I visit the site. The point is that I need `__name__` to equal `'__main__'`. I also just want to know why it doesn't and how to make it equal `__main__`.

## Edit 2

... I just had the epiphany that I do not need to run `app.run()` since that is what Gunicorn is for. Duh.  But I would still like to figure out why `__name__` isn't `'__main__'`

Comment: Why do you need it to be like that? Try visiting `http://127.0.0.2:8000/` when you run it with `guincorn`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python sets `__name__` to `"__main__"` when the script is the entry point for the Python interpreter.  Since Gunicorn imports the script it is running *that* script will not be the entry point and so will not have `__name__` set to `"__main__"`.

Comment: So it will never be "__main__". That totally makes sense now.

Comment: So how to keep __main__ when running python and still make it work with gunicorn ?

Comment: Just use the pattern the question uses - guard your `main` with an `if __name__ == '__main__':` and tell gunicorn what the name of your object is. Gunicorn _imports_ your app and wraps it, so it needs to be able to treat your module as a _library_ (while you want it to run as an **application** when you run `python your_app.py`).